# Redirect the output of verbose jvm to specific file

Tags: java, jvm

Is there a way to redirect the output of jvm which resulted of passing *verbose* the the java process to specific file?

Comment: You mean like redirecting a running process' output from stdout to some file?

Comment: How are you invoking the JVM?  If you are looking to separate out the output added by using `verbose` as opposed to direct all of the output when you happen to be using `verbose`, I'd be surprised If that were possible.

Comment: As with any program, you can redirect output using "> file", resp "2'> othrfile" for stderr. There is nothing specific about "jvm" here.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file for example. Windows console works in similar ways.

Answer (score 5):

#### JDK 8

```
java -verbose -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+LogVMOutput -XX:-DisplayVMOutput -XX:LogFile=test.log
```

#### JDK 9+

```
java -Xlog::file=test.log
```

Comment: wow, I did not think that this was possible in Java 8, nice!